# Parse yaml file to run a for_each loop in terraform for multiple resources creation

Tags: terraform

I have the following `config.yaml` file

```yaml
entities:
  admins:
    someone@somewhere.com
  viewers:
    anotherone@somewhere.com
```

And I want to create vault entities based on the users below the `yaml` nodes `admins` and `viewers`

```
locals {
  config = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))
  admins = keys(local.config["entities"]["admins"]...)
  viewers = keys(local.config["entities"]["viewers"]...)
}

resource "vault_identity_entity" "admins" {
  for_each  = toset(local.admins)

  name      = each.key
  policies  = ["test"]
  metadata  = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}

resource "vault_identity_entity" "viewers" {
  for_each  = toset(local.viewers)

  name      = each.key
  policies  = ["test"]
  metadata  = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```

The code above fails with:

```
│ Error: Invalid expanding argument value
│
│   on ../../../../entities/main.tf line 3, in locals:
│    3:   admins = keys(local.config["entities"]["admins"]...)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling keys(inputMap)
│     │ local.config["entities"]["admins"] is "someone@somewhere.com"
│
│ The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
│ type.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on ../../../../entities/main.tf line 4, in locals:
│    4:   viewers = keys(local.config["entities"]["viewers"]...)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.config["entities"] is object with 2 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

How should I structure my `yaml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the YAML to be a hash of a hash of a list of strings. You can restructure for that like:

```
entities:
  admins:
  - someone@somewhere.com
  viewers:
  - anotherone@somewhere.com
```

This will recast to `map(map(list(string)))` when `yamldecode` from a YAML format string to HCL2.

However, you are also attempting to convert the type with the ellipsis operator `...` in your `locals`, and returning only the keys. I am unsure why you are doing that, and both should be removed:

```
admins = local.config["entities"]["admins"]
viewers = local.config["entities"]["viewers"]
```

Afterwards, you can convert to a `set` type with `toset` like you are doing already, and then leverage that within the `for_each` meta-argument as per usual:

```
for_each = toset(local.admins)
for_each = toset(local.viewers)
```

This will result in the desired behavior.